# Integral of complex rational functions in several variables

Tags: complex-geometry, cv.complex-variables

Let $D\subseteq \mathbb{C}^3$ be an open domain, and let $f:D\to \mathbb{C}$ be a rational function. That is: $f$ can be written as a quotient $f=g/h$ where $g,h\in \mathbb{C}[z_1,z_2,z_3]$.

**Question**: is there any theorem  or algorithm which enables one to write the integral $$\oint_{|z_2|=0.99}\oint_{|z_1|=0.99}fdz_1dz_2$$ as a rational function of $z_3$? 
In the case I am interested in the function $f$ is given as a quotient $f=g/h$ where both $g$ and $h$ decompose as a product of linear polynomials. One can apply of course the residue theorem twice, but I wonder if there is any way which is more direct, as the calculation becomes rather tedious.

**Edit**: the specific function I have is the following:
$$f(a,b,x) = g/h$$ where $$g=(a^{-1}-1)(b^{-1}-1)$$ and $$h=(1-abx)(1-ab^{-1}x)(1-a^{-1}bx)(1-a^{-1}b^{-1}x)(1-ax)^2(1-a^{-1}x)^2(1-bx)^2(1-b^{-1}x)^2.$$
One can easily eliminate the negative powers of $a,b$. The domain $D$ is given by $$D = \{(a,b,x)| |x|<0.1, 0.9<|a|<1, 0.9<|b|<1\}\subseteq \mathbb{C}^3$$

To phrase my question differently: I can apply first the residue theorem for the variable $a$, getting poles of the form $xb$, $x/b$ et cetera, then apply the residue theorem again for the variable $b$ and finally getting a rational function in $x$. I wonder if there is a higher dimensional version of the residue theorem, which enables one to calculate the two integrals directly.

Comment: Could you specify your question, giving a concrete example of $f$ to work with?

Comment: I added an explicit description of the function $f$.

Comment: Do you change your notation in such a way $z_1=a,\,z_2=b, \,z_3=x$? If so, then does the integral $\int_{|a|=1}\int_{|b|=1} f\,da\,db $ exist?

Comment: I did indeed. I change the integral just a bit to make it exist.

Comment: Sorry, it's still unclear to me whether the integral under consideration exists. Can you kindly elaborate your question, giving us more details? TIA.

Comment: I am sorry, I was a bit sloppy here. I changed the definition of the domain $D$. The definition now ensures that none of the linear functions in the denominator becomes zero in $D$. This implies that we are taking an integral of a continuous function on a compact set, which must exist.

Comment: You wrote "where both $g$ and $h$ decompose as a product of linear polynomials". Sorry, but neither your $g$ nor your  $h$ are products of linear polynomials.

Comment: I added the remark that one can get rid easily of the negative powers of $a$ and of $b$ by multiplying both $g$ and $h$ by a high enough power of $a$ and of $b$.

Comment: Yes, but still  there are no products of  linear polynomials. BTW, the references from https://mccme.ru/pdc/2009/xtra/kytmanov/Kytmanov_Research_statement.pdf may be useful for you. Good luck!